# How to solve an ODE with an absolute value?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

I am a bit confused about how to solve an ODE of this type

$y'= \mid x \mid - \mid y \mid $ , $y(0)=0$

Do I need to divide the ODE into four phases :

1. $x>0$ & $y>0$
2. $x>0$ & $y<0$
3. $x<0$ & $y>0$
4. $x<0$ & $y<0$

or is there another approach?

Comment: Note that the solution of this problem is unique, since the right hand side is Lipschitz continuous. So if you can somehow guess a solution and verify it, you are done. Why don't you try that ? :)

Comment: CAS says:$y(x)=\begin{cases}
 x-e^x+1 & x\leq 0 \\
 x+e^{-x}-1 & x>0
\end{cases}$

Comment: But those two equations (above) only answer the situation of (y>0). isn't that right?